# How to get my dictionary discord.py bot to stop looping when adding a line

Tags: python, dictionary, discord, nltk, wordnet

So I found this open source discord.py bot on the internet that uses wordnet to fetch the definition of any given word. It's supposed to first send the part of speech the word is in (Noun, Verb, Adjective) and then below that, there should be multiple definitions of the word.

HOWEVER, the current code keeps looping the entire process. It keeps repeating the parts of speech part when adding each new definition of the word. You can see for yourself what I mean in the the picture below:

[What it looks like now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xeX7d.png)

As you can see, this results in unnecessarily long messages. Instead, i would like if it added all the points beforehand and only sent the finished product. Like this:

Noun

1. ...
2. ...
3. ...
4. ...
5. ...
6. ...

Here is the current code:

```
nltk.download("wordnet")
from collections import defaultdict
from nltk.corpus import wordnet

def format_meaning(word, synsets, m):
  person = str(m.author.mention)
  log = person + ", the definition is:\n\n"
  reply = f"**{word}**\n\n"
  char = 0

  # Group by POS
  grouped = defaultdict(list)

  for synset in synsets:
    grouped[PARTS_OF_SPEECH[synset.pos()]].append(synset.definition())

    for pos, definitions in grouped.items():
      if char > 1250:
        return log + reply
      reply += f"*{pos}*\n"
      char += len(f"*{pos}*\n")
      for counter, definition in enumerate(definitions, 1):
        reply += f"    {counter}. {definition}\n"
        char += len(f"    {counter}. {definition}\n")
        
  return log + reply
```

I've some experience with using Python but this is a bit over my head and i am at a loss over how to get it working. So, any help would be greatly appreciated!